# Vue v3: How to render component on the fly and insert rendered template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use this way of adding Vue app to existing page:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script type="module">
  import DataTable from '{% static 'js/datatable/datatable_app.js' %}'

  let app = Vue.createApp(DataTable)
  window.mounted = app.mount('#app')
</script>
```

In the page code i have this block for mounting app:

```
<div id="app">
      <a rel="link" href="#" @click="openMenu">Link1</a>
      <a rel="link"  href="#" @click="openMenu">Link2</a>
      <a rel="link"  href="#" @click="openMenu">Link3</a>
      <a rel="link"  href="#" @click="openMenu">Link4</a>
</div>
```

and i have small template, that i need to insert right after <a rel="link"> in #app block:

```
        <ul>
            <li @click="setValue">{{ item1 }}</li>
            <li @click="setValue">{{ item2 }}</li>
            <li @click="setValue">{{ item3 }}</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Question is - how can i preload this component, populate with data from main app, render and insert it? I whant to use openMenu() function  from main app to do this and setValue() function to "close" (delete) rendered block from page.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html